# What does a Swap event describe when amount0In and amount0Out are non-0, but amount1In and amount1Out are zero?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap

Take a look at this [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x65e8f861505a47ff5529ac6e367ba86a66830c51d551c52b2576c33c9c11d90c#eventlog),

It describes the following event:

```
amount0In: 104852331424429462
amount0Out: 104642626761580603
amount1In: 0
amount1Out: 0
```

`104852331424429462` WBNB was transferred in exchange for `104852331424429462` WBNB, i.e.

```
a=104852331424429462 = 104,852,331,424,429,462
b=104642626761580603 = 104,642,626,761,580,603
((a-b)/((a+b)/2))*100 = 0.20020020020020027283
```

the exact same amount minus 0.2% [pancakeswap](/questions/tagged/pancakeswap) fee.

There are also events with inverse values, e.g.

```
amount0In: 0
amount0Out: 0
amount1In: 64979813141908818
amount1Out: 64849853515625000
```

What was intended / done here?

Comment: The only possible "use case" for this I can think of is if someone wanted to inflate the trading volume of the pair.

Answer (score 2):

After analyzing the contract interactions and the account history it isn't a regular trade. It appears to be a bot farming rewards then interacting with other pools.

It initially get 0.1046 WBNB as rewards from `0x1b96b92314c44b159149f7e0303511fb2fc4774f` a WBNB-BUSD token pair.

Then uses `0x545cab9e5d1173e26f882efcb7f4046828142f73` and `0x472d5d9266b5794309c353d703fc1a44a864ac82`, a couple of HMNG-WBNB token pairs, to arbitrage the rewards and increase their profits.

At the end it receives 0.1069 WBNB minus 0.0011 for transaction fees.

The event you describe

```
amount0In: 104852331424429462
amount0Out: 104642626761580603
amount1In: 0
amount1Out: 0
```

Is the initial claim of the rewards.